# Jenkins declarative pipeline, trigger my job whenever there is change in symlink

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to solve an issue where I am not using Git for any purpose rather we just want to use Jenkins to trigger our pipeline whenever there is change in the symlink located in a folder and not in the workspace

Comment: I don't think there's any out-of-the-box support for this in Jenkins - you'd have to build something that polls the symlink and tracks deltas.

Comment: If this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085656/jenkins-fails-after-checkout-with-no-error] is solved I can get another way of solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you'll try to use https://plugins.jenkins.io/fstrigger, even that it may not really being supported currently.

Comment: "_The current code does not work with Pipeline projects._"

Comment: Good point @zett42, still, using the 'pipeline syntax' you can generate the 'properties' section for the Jenkinsfile, so I still think it deserves a test.

Comment: Last time I tried it, it didn't work in pipeline when configured through the UI. It could be worth trying out the properties section of the Jenkinsfile.